# Android CameraX - PreviewView not found in Layout

Tags: android

I am trying to implement CameraX and PreviewView. However, FindViewById returns null for my PreviewView. I have tried to implement this function in OnCreate, and now it is not called until a button is pressed.

Any help from anyone who knows what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Does anyone else get the same result?

Here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android.id="@+id/preview_view"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:onClick="on_button_click"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the Java Code

```
package com.example.cameraxtest2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.camera.core.Camera;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector;
import androidx.camera.core.Preview;
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider;
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    void StartCameraPreview() {
        ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;

        ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = null;
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        try {
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
        } catch(ExecutionException | InterruptedException e)  {}

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();

        PreviewView previewView = findViewById(R.id.preview_view);   //<<<<<<Returns null

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider());

        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, cameraSelector, preview);
    }

    public void on_button_click(View clickedView) {
        StartCameraPreview();
    }
}
```

Here is a relevent section of my gradle file

```
        compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha14"
```

Thank You! James

Comment: The Gradle bits are not relevant here, but thanks! What we could use is an idea of where this `StartCameraPreview()` method resides and when/how it is being called. I am assuming that the method resides in an activity. Perhaps you are calling it before you call `setContentView()` to load that layout.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have tried moving it around. It is in a click event for a button on the same layout as the PreviewView.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare - I edited the post to include all of the code.  Thank You!